# Hide logo and page number only for scrolling slides in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r-markdown, ioslides

I produce a deck of ioslides with logo and page number in RStudio with rmarkdown.
If the content is to big for a slide I can add `slides > slide { overflow: scroll; }`to my .css file and supress the logo and page number with `slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {content: '';}` and `slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {background: none;}`.

But I want to keep the logo and page numbers to every page with no overflow. So I tried to reference the css-styles to the `#id` of the overfull page but that doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
Here is what I tried.

My .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Samuel Merk"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: mycss.css
    logo: logo.png
date: "12 Juli 2016"
---



## Very long slide

This is the long slide.

efewg  
sdfg  
sdfg  
sdfg  

sdfg  
sdfg  
sdfg  

  efewg  
sdfg  
sdfg  
sdfg  

sdfg  
sdfg  
sdfg  


## Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

My Customization of the .css file

```
#very-long-slide {
  slides > slide { overflow: scroll; }
  slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {content: '';}
  slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {background: none;}
 }
```

Comment: I dont think anyone is going to be able to help you if you dont provide more code or perhaps a working sample of your issue.

Comment: OK thank's. I added information and code.

Comment: So the problem is, that every slide loses it's page number? What if you try `slides > slide #very-long-slide { ... }`? And maybe use `!important` then.